# Create File in any Path on Mobile Device

Tags: java-me, createfile

I want to create a file on mobile phone and the file path is determined by the user. In my mobile phone (Nokia) the list is that:

Phone Memory:/ , C:/ , Memory Card:/, E:/.

The file is created in Memory Card:/ and  E:/ but in the other path I get error.

This application  will run any mobile phone and if I experienced this problem for only one mobile device I might this problem for all mobile device. How could I deal with? 
Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think this is possible, but you can connect to the mobile device with the MTP-Protocol.
Here the Java MTP libary http://code.google.com/p/jmtp/.

```
package test;

import jmtp.PortableDevice;
import jmtp.PortableDeviceManager;
import jmtp.PortableDeviceObject;
import jmtp.PortableDeviceStorageObject;

public class FileConnectionTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PortableDeviceManager manager = new PortableDeviceManager();
        PortableDevice device = manager.getDevices()[0]; 

        // Connect to my mp3-player
        device.open();
        System.out.println(device.getModel());
        System.out.println("---------------");

        // Iterate over deviceObjects
        for(PortableDeviceObject object : device.getRootObjects()) {

            // If the object is a storage object
            if(object instanceof PortableDeviceStorageObject) {
                PortableDeviceStorageObject storage = (PortableDeviceStorageObject)object;

                for(PortableDeviceObject o2 :  storage.getChildObjects()){
                    System.out.println(o2.getName());

                }              
            }
        }
        manager.getDevices()[0].close();
    }
}
```

Console output...

```
Sansa Clip+ 8GB
---------------
Music
Playlists
Record
Podcasts
Audiobooks
Service
DevIcon.fil
Albums
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [nokia forum discussion.](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?76063-how-to-read-text-file-in-j2me) It will helps you.